# how can i keep values after hitting submit

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a Submit Page button on my Apex page. If I click on it, it sets the values, sends the form and refresh my page.

Is it possible to keep field values, or repopulate them somehow after page refresh?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is default behaviour unless something has been done to remove the session state data. Check your page processes for something that 'resets cache'.

Also check the branch to ensure it's not clearing cache for the page you're re-opening.

Also check the source of the items. Is it using source definition "Always", or "Only when session state is null". What's the source?

Comment: Thank you very much Scott, I am looking for a smarter way to do this, by using less plsql.